# Dropbear terminates before LUKS password prompt on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, encryption, luks, dropbear

I'm trying to use `dropbear` as a ssh server to unlock an encrypted partition which was created during Debian 8.2 setup. It boots to the password prompt (and unlocks if correct password is typed) but before the prompt appears, dropbear exits with `Early exit: Terminated by signal`. The system is pingable - I've added `DROPBEAR=y`, added correct `DEVICE/IP` settings in the initramfs conf file,  did a `NO_START=0` in `/etc/default/dropbear` file and did `update-initramfs`.

If I'm adding a `sleep 60` in the `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/dropbear` script I am able to connect to the dropbear ssh. But after the sleep it executes `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/dropbear` wich kills dropbear right before the password prompt appears.

Why is the init-bottom script called and how to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

After days of trying and testing, the solution (or the problem) is very simple: be sure to have your `/` mount point **inside** your encrypted volumes - if not, the `init-bottom` script is called right after the `init-premount` scripts (because the `/` doesn't need to be decrypted).